# Foundation 6 Dropdown menu

Tags: zurb-foundation

The drop down menu in foundation is not working in mobile view.
who solve this issue?
`<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 1</a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown menu works fine on mobile, try it here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html

Make sure *jquery.js*, *foundation.js* and *foundation.dropdown.js* have been included on your page before continuing. For example, add the following before the closing `<body>` tag:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have provided proper foundation CSS on top of the page & proper foundation js and jquery on the bottom of the page.

If you a beginner in the foundation, you can use Foundation's ready-made [building blocks](http://zurb.com/building-blocks).